# Calling a function with URL parameter to get argument for .as_view() Is it possible?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard, django-formtools

Here's my current code:

```
form_list = [PilotForm, BriefingsForm]
...
url(r'^inspections/(?P<inspection_type_id>[0-9]+)/new-inspection/$', InspectionWizard.as_view(form_list), name='new_inspection'),
```

what I want to achieve is so that I could have a function that would dynamically return form_list based on inspection_type_id (url param):

it would look like:

```
def get_form_list(inspection_type_id):
    forms_list = []
    # dynamically filter forms and add to forms_list
    return forms_list
    ...
url(r'^inspections/(?P<inspection_type_id>[0-9]+)/new-inspection/$', InspectionWizard.as_view(get_form_list(inspection_type_id), name='new_inspection'),
```

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: Are you trying to merge a list into a url string?  I am not sure what you are doing with url().

Comment: You are doing things in a wrong way. You should call function from Django view. Try to call it from `as_view()` is big design mistake.